# How to add views to the steps of a roadmap in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am looking to add views (or workflow) to a roadmap steps in sapui5. I am new to sapui5, can any one help me out with this?

My code:

```
<script>
    //create the RoadMap control
    var oRMap = new sap.ui.commons.RoadMap("rMap");

    //create the RoadMap steps
    var oStep1 = new sap.ui.commons.RoadMapStep("step1", {label: "Step 1"});
    var oStep2 = new sap.ui.commons.RoadMapStep("step2", {label: "Step 2"});
    var oStep3 = new sap.ui.commons.RoadMapStep("step3", {label: "Step 3"});

    //add steps to the RoadMap
    oRMap.addStep(oStep1);
    oRMap.addStep(oStep2);
    oRMap.addStep(oStep3);

    //Set the first step as selected
    oRMap.setSelectedStep("step1");

    //Set the number of visible steps
    oRMap.setNumberOfVisibleSteps(3);

    //Place the control on the UI   
    oRMap.placeAt("sample1");
</script>
```

This will show three steps in my application. What I want is to add views to each of the steps.

Say I want to add a date picker for first step, table for second step and so on..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in many ways. I would create a container below your roadmap, where you display different views, one for each step. You could use a NavContainer which handles the navigation

---

EDIT: it can be as simple as this (I used XMLView notation since I find these a far easier to write, but the same applies for JSViews of course):

```
<VBox>
    <c:RoadMap id="roadMap">
        <c:steps>
            <c:RoadMapStep id="step1" label="Step 1" />
            <c:RoadMapStep id="step2" label="Step 2" />
            <c:RoadMapStep id="step3" label="Step 3" />
        </c:steps>
    </c:RoadMap>
    <NavContainer width="100%" height="20rem">
        <Page title="Step 1">
            <DatePicker />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://feeder-arrow" text="Next step" press="doNext" />
        </Page>
        <Page title="Step 2">
            <Text text="Some data"/>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://nav-back"     text="Previous step" press="doPrevious" />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://feeder-arrow" text="Next step"     press="doNext" />
        </Page>
        <Page title="Step 3">
            <Text text="Some more data"/>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://nav-back"     text="Previous step" press="doPrevious" />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://feeder-arrow" text="Next step"     press="doNext" />
        </Page>
    </NavContainer>
</VBox>
```

In the `doNext` and `doPrevious` you then increment/decrement the roadmap's `selectedStep` property with the correct step ID, and you perform a `nav.to(target)` or `nav.back()`

See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.NavContainer/preview for info in the NavContainer

Comment: Can you please help me with some code, as I m very new to this... @qualiture.